# jenkins can't archive the debug apk

Tags: android, continuous-integration, jenkins, apk

I'm trying to set up jenkins for building android apps and archiving builds.
However, it seems that I can't archive the debug apk. 
Ant is run with "clean debug" and "archive artifacts" is selected. I tried with **/*.apk and with bin/test-debug.apk, which is the file I want(and is visible through the jenkins workspace browser.

console log:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@eb3f66
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision bae064038961f07de92252f6f65d222e90d2d871 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@eb3f66
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from /home/andraz/test/.git
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Commencing build of Revision bae064038961f07de92252f6f65d222e90d2d871 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Checking out Revision bae064038961f07de92252f6f65d222e90d2d871 (origin/HEAD, origin/master)
Warning : There are multiple branch changesets here
[workspace] $ ant -Dsdk.dir=/home/andraz/android-sdk-linux clean debug
Buildfile: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/build.xml

-pre-clean:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin
   [delete] Deleting directory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/gen

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-setup:
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/res
     [echo] Gathering info for test...
    [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 17
    [setup] Project Target: Android 2.2
    [setup] API level: 8
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] Resolving library dependencies:
    [setup] No library dependencies.
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
    [setup] 
    [setup] ------------------
    [setup] WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.

-build-setup:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/classes

-pre-build:

-code-gen:
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/classes.dex...

-crunch:
   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/res
   [crunch] To destination dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache

-package-resources:
     [aapt] Creating full resource package...

-package:
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.
[apkbuilder] Creating test-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...

-post-package:

-do-debug:
 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
     [echo] Debug Package: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/test-debug.apk
[propertyfile] Creating new property file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/build.prop
[propertyfile] Updating property file: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-project/workspace/bin/build.prop

-post-build:

debug:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
Archiving artifacts
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "**/*.apk". Configuration error?
Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

it seems to me that file is generated but somehow not found. 
also if I chose to archive bin/test* it stores test-debug-unaligned.apk.d, test.apk_, test.apk.d but no apks
any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the file is simply not there when archiving happens. As a last build step run shell script that executes `ls -l bin` and see if the file is indeed there by examining the console output.

Comment: test-debug.apk shows up, and even has same owner and permissions as e.g. test.ap_.d(which can be archived) but archiving fails with: ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "bin/test-debug.apk". Configuration error?

Comment: Can you post `config.xml` for the job?

Comment: got it to work. i had exclusion for bin/*.apk in config.xml. don't know how it got there. thanks

Comment: Your artifacts need to save on $WORKSPACE